# Does Spark Kafka streaming 0.8 indirect stream KafkaUtils.createStream updateWaterMark save offsets to Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper

I am bound to use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using deprecated Functionality

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, zkArgs, consumerGroupId, topicMap)

kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

I read that using watermarks manually is done so:

```
//      enabling watermarking upon success
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  ....
  .set("zookeeper.hosts", zkArgs)
  .set("enable.auto.commit", "false")
  ....

df.withWatermark("eventTime", "10 minutes")
  .write .....
```

Following the class trail led me to classes such as EventTimeWatermark ...

In another place I read that I should write the offsets myself something like:

```
def saveOffsets(zkClient:  ZkClient, zkPath: String, rdd: RDD[_]): Unit = {
  val offsetsRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  val offsetsRangesStr = offsetsRanges.map(offsetRange => s"${offsetRange.partition}:${offsetRange.fromOffset}")
  .mkString(",")

  ZkUtils.updatePersistentPath(zkClient, zkPath, offsetsRangesStr)
}
```

Does the

```
df.withWatermark("eventTime", "10 minutes")
      .write
```

..... eventually update the watermark in the Zookeeper? or in another mechanism on the cluster running spark?

Answer (score 1):

Since watermarking is done only in Spark streaming, late messages when picked from Kafka are just ignored in Spark.

Kafka offsets are updated as and when messages are read.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking

Comment: You are describing the direct stream approach https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html. I think the watermarking in this case is persisted in Zookeeper but I'm not sure

Comment: @RubberDuck: Thanks, why do you think watermarks need to be stored. In spark streaming, I feel watermark is more like a configuration, df.withWatermark("eventTime", "10 minutes"), means ignore all messages arriving after 10 mins delay. That's all need to be stored. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Ive been scouring the documentation and am not sure, I'll try to test this theory. From what I understand zookeeper persists offsets per .set("group.id", consumerGroupId). And probably is given a hint as how far back to go excluding those events

Comment: I wonder if the watermark is a convenience method for updating the zookeeper. I want to assure conditional offset persistence because I provision the Hadoop cluster then deprovision it and therefore can't persist there. And also in case a microbatch fails.

Comment: @RubberDuck Watermarks is unrelated to offsets. In a rough sense, the watermark is the delay boundary. There are multiple algorithms to calculate watermarks. For details, you can read the blog post from the father of watermarks itself https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102

Comment: Are you saying there is no connection between setting enable.auto.commit to false and watermarking? I know that later Kafka versions took the group handling functionality from zookeeper. How then do I conditionally commit the consumption of an event?

Comment: enable.auto.commit: false is not related to watermarking at all. Please read the above mentioned blog post or various talks by the same author. He invented the various algorithms behind watermarking and is staff engineer at Google. His book on streaming is also very popular.

Comment: You are right! I was mislead by the same naming in an internal API. The question is confusing because I was confused!

Comment: How do I configure indirect stream to never update the offset?